# My custom view will not save it's state

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-view, android-viewholder

I created a custom view with the following code (edited for brevity):

```
public class StampView extends View {

    // View State items
    private String stampText, stampTimeStamp;
    private int stampIconId;
    private boolean stamped;

    public StampView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        // REMOVED
    }

    /**
     *
     * See: http://trickyandroid.com/saving-android-view-state-correctly/
     *
     * @return Returns a Parcelable object containing the view's current dynamic
     * state, or null if there is nothing interesting to save.
     * @see #onRestoreInstanceState(Parcelable)
     * @see #saveHierarchyState(SparseArray)
     * @see #dispatchSaveInstanceState(SparseArray)
     * @see #setSaveEnabled(boolean)
     */
    @Nullable @Override protected Parcelable onSaveInstanceState() {
        Parcelable superState = super.onSaveInstanceState();
        SavedState ss = new SavedState(superState);

        // We need to save 4 extra things to save state.
        // StampText string
        ss.stampText = stampText;
        // Icon ID int
        ss.stampIconId = stampIconId;

        // Timestamp string
        ss.stampTimestamp = stampTimeStamp;

        // Stamped boolean
        ss.stamped = stamped;

        // An example
        // ss.state = customState;
        return ss;
    }

    @Override
    public void onRestoreInstanceState(Parcelable state) {
        SavedState ss = (SavedState) state;
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(ss.getSuperState());

        // our custom saved state items
        setStampIcon(ss.stampIconId);
        setStampTitleText(ss.stampText);
        setStampTimeStampText(ss.stampTimestamp);
        setStamped(ss.stamped);
    }

    /**
     * Extending the BaseSavedState allows us to extend state saving and save our own custom state variables above.
     *
     **/
    static class SavedState extends BaseSavedState {
        int stampIconId;
        String stampText, stampTimestamp;
        boolean stamped;

        SavedState(Parcelable superState) {
            super(superState);
        }

        // Reading In from a Parcel
        private SavedState(Parcel in) {
            super(in);
            stampIconId = in.readInt();
            stampText = in.readString();
            stampTimestamp = in.readString();
            stamped = in.readByte() != 0;  //myBoolean == true if byte != 0
        }

        // Writing to a Parcel
        @Override
        public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
            super.writeToParcel(out, flags);
            // I assume order matters, since we don't seem to be writing the key values
            out.writeInt(stampIconId);
            out.writeString(stampText);
            out.writeString(stampTimestamp);
            out.writeByte((byte) (stamped ? 1 : 0));     //if myBoolean == true, byte == 1
        }

        public static final Parcelable.Creator<SavedState> CREATOR
                = new Parcelable.Creator<SavedState>() {
            public SavedState createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
                return new SavedState(in);
            }

            public SavedState[] newArray(int size) {
                return new SavedState[size];
            }
        };
    }


    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        //REMOVED
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.draw(canvas);
        Rect bounds = new Rect(0,0,mWidth,mHeight);

        if(stamped){
            // Draw the stamp

        } else {
            // Draw a placeholder instead
        }
    }

    public void constructStampViewFromPOI(POI poi){
        //removed
    }

    private void setStampTitleText (String titleString){
        this.stampText = titleString;
    }

    private void setStampTimeStampText (String tsString){
        this.stampTimeStamp = tsString;
    }



    private void setStampIcon(int collectionIconId) {
        // removed
    }

    public void setStamped(boolean bool) {
        this.stamped = bool;
        this.invalidate();
    }
}
```

My custom view is fairly simple, it can draw out 2 versions of itself, depending on a boolean called 'stamped'.  You can see this in the draw method.  I placed this custom view in a Viewholder within a RecyclerView of 6 items.  My activity should have the following layout:

`Viewholder #1 - Stamp view (#1 data)
 Viewholder #2 - Placeholder view
 Viewholder #3 - Placeholder view
 Viewholder #4 - Placeholder view
 Viewholder #5 - Placeholder view
 Viewholder #6 - Stamped view (#6 data)`

But if I debug my activity I see my custom view get drawn 6 times, once for each viewholder in the recyclerview and then for some reason it re-draws all 6 a second time.  On this second pass it messes up the state of the StampView in Viewholder #5 using the data for viewholder #6.  I end up with this layout:

`Viewholder #1 - Stamp view (#1 data)
 Viewholder #2 - Placeholder view
 Viewholder #3 - Placeholder view
 Viewholder #4 - Placeholder view
 Viewholder #5 - Stamped view (#6 data)
 Viewholder #6 - Stamped view (#6 data)`

Clicking on a viewholder takes me to a DetailsActivity, if I do that and then return back to my RecyclerView I see this layout:

`Viewholder #1 - Stamp view (#1 data)
 Viewholder #2 - Placeholder view
 Viewholder #3 - Placeholder view
 Viewholder #4 - Stamped view (#6 data)
 Viewholder #5 - Stamped view (#6 data)
 Viewholder #6 - Stamped view (#6 data)`

If I do this two more times I'll finally end up with this messed up layout:

`Viewholder #1 - Stamp view (#1 data)
 Viewholder #2 - Stamped view (#6 data)
 Viewholder #3 - Stamped view (#6 data)
 Viewholder #4 - Stamped view (#6 data)
 Viewholder #5 - Stamped view (#6 data)
 Viewholder #6 - Stamped view (#6 data)`

It seems to me that my custom view is NOT saving it's state and/or confusing it's state when I have multiple instances on the screen.  I found [this post](http://trickyandroid.com/saving-android-view-state-correctly/) that mentions this sort of problem and tried to implement it's way of saving state, but I cannot get the onSaveInstanceState method to fire within my view. I've tried everything mentioned, including `setSaveEnabled(true);` both inside my custom view and inside the viewholder, and I've tried setting a custom id for each instantiation of the custom view...and nothing has worked.

- Can someone explain to me what I'm doing wrong?
- Am I correct that this is a state saving problem?
- How and where am I supposed to be saving my custom view state? Inside the view or is the activity supposed to be saving the state of my view, since it's a part of the viewholder?

---

EDIT:
Here is the viewholder code if it's helpful:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(POI_View_Holder holder, int position) {

    //Instead lets use the viewholder bind method to assign content
    holder.bind(mPOIslist.get(position), listener);
}

static class POI_View_Holder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        // Variables for the ViewHolder
        private TextView name;
        private TextView positionText;
        private StampView stampView;

        POI_View_Holder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.poi_nameTV);
            positionText= itemView.findViewById(R.id.poi_positionTV);
            stampView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.poi_StampView);

//            stampView.setSaveEnabled(true); // force state saving
//            stampView.setId(getPosition());
        }

        public void bind(final POI poi, final OnPOIClickListener listener){

            // Set POI information in viewHolder
            name.setText(poi.getName());
            positionText.setText(String.valueOf(poi.getCollectionPosition()));

            if(poi.isStamped()){
                stampView.setElevation(4);
                stampView.setTranslationZ(4);
                stampView.setClipToOutline(true);
                // stampView.invalidate();
                stampView.constructStampViewFromPOI(poi);
            } else {
                stampView.setElevation(0);
                stampView.setTranslationZ(0);
            }
            Log.d("ViewHolder-", "bind: method fired");
            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override public void onClick(View view) {
                    listener.OnPOIClick(poi);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

---

EDIT2:  And here is my activity save state code:

```
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle state) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(state);

    // Save layoutManager state
    mListState = mLayoutManager.onSaveInstanceState();
    state.putParcelable(LIST_STATE_KEY, mListState);

    mCollectionList = Parcels.wrap(mListOfPOIsInCollection);
    state.putParcelable(COLLECTION_ARRAYLIST_STATE_KEY,mCollectionList);
}

protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle state) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(state);

    // Retrieve list state and list/item positions
    if(state != null) {
        mListState = state.getParcelable(LIST_STATE_KEY);
        //mCollectionList = state.getParcelable(COLLECTION_ARRAYLIST_STATE_KEY);
        mListOfPOIsInCollection = Parcels.unwrap(state.getParcelable(COLLECTION_ARRAYLIST_STATE_KEY));
    }
}

@Override protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    if (mListState != null) {
        mLayoutManager.onRestoreInstanceState(mListState);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`View.onSaveInstanceState()` and `View.onRestoreInstanceState(Parcelable)` are meant to be invoked by the system when your view is destroyed and then recreated along with an activity, perhaps when you rotate your phone. They are not used in any way by `RecyclerView`.

This sounds to me like you have at least one problem, and possibly two.

First, in your adapter's `onBindViewHolder()` method, you need to make sure that you always set the state of every sub-view. Frequently people run into problems where they only set the state of a sub-view some of the time, and this causes problems when a view is recycled. For instance:

```
if (myItem.isStamped()) {
    holder.stampView.setStamped(true);
}
```

This will break if your view is recycled and re-bound to a non-stamped data item. Because you only set the state of `holder.stampView` when the stamp is present, you aren't *clearing* it when the stamp isn't present. Instead, you should write:

```
if (myItem.isStamped()) {
    holder.stampView.setStamped(true);
} else {
    holder.stampView.setStamped(false);
}
```

or just

```
holder.stampView.setStamped(myItem.isStamped());
```

Second, it sounds possible that your adapter's data isn't be saved/restored correctly. I can't really speak to this since I don't have any of your activity code, but you could leverage `Activity.onSaveInstanceState(Bundle)` and the `savedInstanceState` bundle passed to `onCreate()` to save it.

Comment: Thank you ben for the response.  Perhaps this is part of my problem.  My onBindViewHolder is pretty bare, since I was instead building the viewholder in the viewholder.bind method instead.  I'll add the method above so you can see it

Comment: Ben, I just tried your suggest and that indeed solved my problem! Thank you.  But can you explain to me where exactly my custom view state is being saved?  Since I have a custom view in each viewholder and they all have a member variable (AKA state) that needs to be remember, doesn't the custom view need to have its own onSaveInstanceState method? As described here --> http://trickyandroid.com/saving-android-view-state-correctly/.  Mine doesn't seem to need it.